# How to make font on full height

Tags: css, height, centering

I need center to center some text on X and Y axes. I noticed that my text is not on full height, which is best solution to give text full height?

I tried to center with:
1. Line height
2. Transform
3. Flex
4. Table - table cell - vertical align

**HTML**:

```
<div class="block">
        <p> 3 </p>
      </div>
```

**SCSS**:

```
.block {
    display: table;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-size: 14px;
    background-color: #ecf3f5;
    border: 1px solid #c9dee4;
    margin-right: 20px;

    p {
      display: table-cell;
      vertical-align: middle;
      text-align: center;
    }
}
```

[What I meant with full height](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HrjoR.png)

This height really matter, for [Small font](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gwqEn.png) it's not visible but with
[Large font](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p2CKA.png) it's really un-centered.

I expect to center this text.

Comment: You may want to adjust the line-height. It will depend on the font.

Answer (score 0):

I think flex is the best and universal method to center element on X and Y, so add 
`display: flex;justify-content: center;align-items: center;` to you parent block. After that you can use anyone font-height what you want.

```css
.block {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-size: 14px;
    background-color: #ecf3f5;
    border: 1px solid #c9dee4;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
p {
    line-height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <p> 3 </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, un-alignment was caused by font family, in my case I used Helvetica, after change text alignment fixed.

https://giphy.com/gifs/SYFl4xIvOdFS6e8X9q/html5